# Will OTM Vanilla Put equal to OTM Vanilla Call with different relative strike?

Tags: black-scholes, put-call-duality

I wanted to test if my strike moves 0.01 away from my current spot for OTM Call and Put. Say I have the following parameters:

For put: $Spot = 1, \sigma = 1, K_p = 0.99 , r = 0, q = 0, $

For call: $Spot = 1, \sigma = 1, K_c = 1.01 , r = 0, q = 0$

However, using fOption package in R yields the following result:
[image]

OTM Call option will have the higher price than OTM put.

I am wondering what is reason behind. Could it be the Geometric Brownian Motion assumption with lognormal distribution of spots?

Appreciate if anyone could provide some ideas on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the Black-Merton-Scholes model, and also for a limited class of stochastic volatility models (when volatility is not correlated to the asset), the following relationship holds:

$$
C(S,K) = \frac{K}{S} P(S, S^2/K)
$$

This relationship is called **put-call symmetry**. Here is a short introduction:

[PCS](https://www.risklatte.xyz/Articles/QuantitativeFinance/QF67.php)

Also, note that under geometric Brownian motion, $1+x$ is not equidistant from 1 as $1 - x$ where in your example $x=0.01$. You need to look at log-differences.

Comment: Understood, thanks. It's basically due to difference in log of both from current spot of 1.